# Is it some way to enable method/variable name autocomplete suggestion for VSCode?

Tags: autocomplete, autofill

I have noticed that method naming is extremely routine.

But can't find the way to enable autocomplete for methods/variables names in order it works like google search requests autocomplete works. Is there some setting, tool or extension or snippet for this?

Comment: Does this help you?: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense